# Showing SQLite entry in HTML using Django

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

I want to show my `text` entry in SQLite database. however it is not showing up.
My page loads file but it doesn't show my `text` db entry.
I am getting an error saying `could not parse {{% text %}}`

i hav gone into my django admin page and added in some text into my db `text` portion of the db. i dont know why it isn't showing up on my webpage.

MODELS.PY

```
from django.db import models

class Datadata(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
```

VIEWS.PY

```
from .models import Datadata

def index(request):
show_this_text = Datadata(models.Model)
return render(request, "index.html", {})
```

INDEX.HTML

```
{% load static %}
<h1>{{ show_this_text.text }}</h1>
```

Comment: In your views python file, query the model and pass it to Django as a context.

Comment: How do i query the model in my `def index`?

Comment: @zenalc i have updated the views.py like you said but it still dent seem to be working. any ideas?